# How can I expand the line where we drag the point?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have this figure as we see on the picture. How can we

1. Make the line (where we drag) longer? For example as long as the red line.
2. We want to have a new output that returns the value in a array (for example the alphabet) in the squarre as shown in the picture, how can I do that? So when we drag for number 2 the letter B should appear in the squarre and if we drag to number 3 the letter C should be in the squarre.

[image]

This is my code:

css:

```
svg {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

js:

```
// Just setup, not related to problem.
const svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 500);
    
const circle = svg.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", "150")
    .attr("cy", "150")
    .attr("r", "100")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "black");
    
const polygon = svg.append("polygon")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "blue");
    
const circleElement = circle.node();
const ranger = d3.select("#ranger").on("input", update);
const label = d3.select("label");

// This function contains all the relevant logic.
function update() {
  let count = ranger.node().value;
  label.text(count);
  // Calculate step length as circumference / number of points.
  const step = circleElement.getTotalLength() / count; 
  // Build an array of all points on the circle.
  const data = Array.from({length: count}, (_, i) => {
    const point = circleElement.getPointAtLength(i * step);   // Get coordinates of next point.
    return `${point.x},${point.y}`; 
  });
  polygon.attr("points", data.join(" "));
}

update();
```

and html:

```
 <center>
 <div class="centered">

Number of side of the polygon.
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
    <p>
  <input id="ranger" type="range" min="3" max="32" value="5">
  <label for="ranger"></label>
</p>

</div>
</center>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.fromCharCode(65,66,67) // "ABC"` can help you here. This function will return a string made up of one or more character codes that are given as arguments.

And, of course, the `#ranger` input element can be made wider by simply defining a width for it with e. g.: `#ranger {width:100%}`.

```js
// Just setup, not related to problem.
const svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
.attr("width", 500)
.attr("height", 500);

const circle = svg.append("circle")
.attr("cx", "150")
.attr("cy", "150")
.attr("r", "100")
.attr("fill", "none")
.attr("stroke", "black");

const polygon = svg.append("polygon")
.attr("fill", "none")
.attr("stroke", "blue");

const circleElement = circle.node();
const ranger = d3.select("#ranger").on("input", update);
const label = d3.select("label");

// This function contains all the relevant logic.
function update() {
  const names=["io", "po", "ppplk", "uiui"];
  let count = ranger.node().value;
  label.text(String.fromCharCode(+count+62)+`: ${count} faces - ${names[count-3]??"(out of range)"}`);
  // Calculate step length as circumference / number of points.
  const step = circleElement.getTotalLength() / count; 
  // Build an array of all points on the circle.
  const data = Array.from({length: count}, (_, i) => {
const point = circleElement.getPointAtLength(i * step);   // Get coordinates of next point.
return `${point.x},${point.y}`; 
  });
  polygon.attr("points", data.join(" "));
}

update();
```

```css
#ranger {width:100%}
svg {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<center>
 <div class="centered">

Number of side of the polygon.
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
<p>
  <input id="ranger" type="range" min="3" max="32" value="5">
  <label for="ranger"></label>
</p>

</div>
</center>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. One question: The count-output disappered. Can we have both the counter and the 'letter' output?

Comment: That can easily be done, check my update.

Comment: My last question is. Say I have an array with random strings rarter than the alphabet: let say ["io", "po", "ppplk", "uiui"], how should the code be then. So output 1 is: io: 3 faces. Output 2 is: po, 4 faces. And so on.

Comment: Ok, check my updated version again.

Comment: How can we remove the letters from the alphabet from the output?

Comment: Hey, look at the code I provided: `label.text(String.fromCharCode(+count+62)+\`: ${count} faces - ${names[count-3]??"(out of range)"}\`);`. If you leave out `String.fromCharCode(+count+62)+` you should get closer to what you want. Btw: SO is not a "free coding service". It is a place where you can get help when you are stuck in your own coding projects.